# Problems toggling animation play state

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to start/stop the rotate animation with a button. Not sure what I'm doing something wrong. I'd rather avoid JQuery if possible....I'm already in above my head.

```
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
    #spinner {
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
    border: 1px dashed;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 2em;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
function spin() {
    var spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");

    if (spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState === 'running') {
        spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused';
        document.body.className = 'paused';
    } else {
        spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running';
        document.body.className = '';
    }
}
}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id="spinner">spin!</div>
<button onClick="spin();">start/stop</button>

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uc9c5/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want it starting on page load or stopped? Check this - http://jsfiddle.net/uc9c5/2/

Comment: that's perfect. What was I doing wrong?! The only slight thing I see is that it flashes the first frame up before pausing. Is this unavoidable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in your jsFiddle you were running it `onLoad` in your jsFiddle when you should have been using the `No wrap in <head> section` option.

Secondly, I've made changes to your CSS - namely, changing `-webkit-animation-play-state:running;` to `-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;` as the initial state, ready for the function call to start the animation.

**[Here's a working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uc9c5/2/)**

**Edit:** In regard to the flicker, it seems like sadly it's a **[webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114783).**

Comment: ahhhh shame on the flicker. Thanks anyway. This will only be in chrome though yes? To make compatible I have to add in:      "-moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;" how will I need to change the  JS?

Comment: If you know the syntax for the others, you can just include them in your css/javascript exactly how you included the webkit version

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 8.1... the circle keep turning and the animation-play-state is totally ignored. God damn you Apple!

Comment: There are still problem in ios safari. Once you play you can't pause it any more. Check your jsFiddle in ios devices with safari.

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your code. The click is not triggered. This should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/uc9c5/3/

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){

    var spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");

    if (!spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState) {        
        spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused';
    } else if (spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState === 'paused') {
        spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running';      
    } else if (spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState === 'running') {
        spinner.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused';       
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wonder why my response was first accepted and afterwards unaccepted. Oh well

Comment: Zennith actually commented before he posted a full answer so I thought they deserved the full credit. Sorry if I caused offence

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thought that there was something wrong with my code.